# Omniauth Facebook Ruby on Rails image_size

Tags: ruby-on-rails, omniauth

I am retrieving the data from the Facebook from like this. I want to get the image in a specific width and height, how can I do it?

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :password, :username, :oauth_token, :provider, :uid, :oauth_expires_at, :picture, :email, :name

def self.from_omniauth(auth)
  where(auth.slice(:provider, :uid)).first_or_initialize.tap do |user|
    user.provider = auth.provider
    user.uid = auth.uid
    user.name = auth.info.name
    user.username = auth.extra.username
    user.email = auth.info.email
    user.picture = auth.info.image
    user.oauth_token = auth.credentials.token
    user.oauth_expires_at = Time.at(auth.credentials.expires_at)
    user.save!
end
end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [dragonfly](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/projects/dragonfly) or [imagery](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/projects/imagery) to play with images once you download or use css to display the image in a different size on the page.

Answer (score 0):

### Solution

You can set in devise.rb the following attribute:

```
  provider :facebook, ENV['APP_ID'], ENV['APP_SECRET'],
    scope: 'email,user_birthday,read_stream', image_size: 'large'
```

The options for image_size are the following, I am quoting the Wiki from Facebook Omniauth. The link is below.

For setting the image to a specific size I would use Css property height, additionally you will need to **delete the account** and **restart the server** to get the image-link in the new size format, because the call to the     `def self.from_omniauth(auth)` is only performed when the user creates the account.

> Set the size for the returned image url in the auth hash. Valid options include square (50x50), small (50 pixels wide, variable height), normal (100 pixels wide, variable height), or large (about 200 pixels wide, variable height). Additionally, you can request a picture of a specific size by setting this option to a hash with :width and :height as keys. This will return an available profile picture closest to the requested size and requested aspect ratio. If only :width or :height is specified, we will return a picture whose width or height is closest to the requested size, respectively.

https://github.com/mkdynamic/omniauth-facebook